# Redirection (ip nat static) with filtering

Tags: cisco, access-control-list, dnat

I want to apply a D-NAT on my Cisco router to access my management IPBX server via the Internet and I have successfully done it with this command:

```
(config)# ip nat inside source static tcp 10.1.1.254 80 41.25.130.47 8080
```

and to access to my server I type `41.25.130.47:8080`.

But my problem is that everyone can access my server and I want to restrict access just for the `193.50.30.0/24` network so is there any solution to do that please?

Additional Info:
IP WAN router : 41.25.130.47
IP IPBX : 10.1.1.254

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that default policy is dropping, you have to allow forwarding for port 8080 packets coming from source net you desire.

Comment: thanks for response , so can i do that with route-map ?? and how please?

Comment: AFAIK you have to use access-list. Take a look here: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/access-lists/26448-ACLsamples.html#anc10